# When I use variables that are defined in a code that will be pasted in another file it shall not be printed in the file. Why?

Tags: bash

```
echo "x=0
while true; do
((i++))
cp file1 file1$x
done
" >> file1
```

`
When I use variables that are defined in a code that will be pasted in another file it shall not be printed in the file. Why? And how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking why `cp file1 file1$x` becomes `cp file1 file1` or `cp file1 file1foo` (where `foo` is the value of `$x` in the current shell), then it's because the `$x` undergoes variable expansion when inside double quotes.

You can prevent variable expansion by using *single* quotes:

```
echo 'x=0
while true; do
((i++))
cp file1 file1$x
done
' >> file1
```

or (more idiomatically) by using a here document with a quoted terminator

```
cat >> file1 << 'EOF'
x=0
while true; do
((i++))
cp file1 file1$x
done
EOF
```